# Is the complement of a given language context-free?

Tags: automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I have a problem with finding out if the complement of language L is context free.

$L = \{ ww : w \in \{a,b\}^{*} \wedge \text{ }w \text{ number of }a\text{'s in }w \equiv \text{number of }b\text{'s in }w \text{ (mod 3)} \}$

Is there any clever way to answer this question? I have no idea how to deal easily with this modulo 3 requirement . I would be grateful for any help.

Ok. And what about proving it is context free if it is not equal in `mod3?`

Comment: What exactly does the mod 3 requirement mean? Are you saying that the amount of $a$'s $\equiv$ amount of $b$'s mod $3$?

Comment: yes.this is what i mean.

Comment: My bet is no, no. No for L and no for the complement. But I don't even have an idea who to prove it.

Comment: ok and how we can describe complement of L at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language is indeed context-free. Let $A = \{a,b\}$ and let
$$
L_0 = \{ww \mid w \in A^*\} \quad \text{and} \quad L_1 = \{ w \mid |w|_a \equiv |w|_b \bmod 3\}
$$
Then $L = L_0 \cap L_1$ and thus its complement $L^c$ is equal to $L_0^c \cup L_1^c$. Then $L_1$ is regular language, since $L_1 = f^{-1}(0)$ where $f$ is the monoid morphism from $A^*$ to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(w) = |w|_a - |w|_b$. It follows that $L_1^c$ is regular and it suffices to show that $L_0^c$ is context-free. This is more difficult, but this question [Show that $\{ xy \mid |x| = |y|, x \not= y \}$ is context-free](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/307/show-that-xy-%E2%88%A3-x-y-x-%E2%89%A0-y-is-context-free/14550#14550) already received an answer on Computer Science Stack Exchange.

EDIT. Here is an automaton for $L_1$. The set of states is $Q = \{0, 1, 2\}$, $0$ is the initial state and the unique final state. The transitions are $0 \xrightarrow{a} 1 \xrightarrow{a} 2 \xrightarrow{a} 0$ and  $0 \xrightarrow{b} 2 \xrightarrow{b} 1 \xrightarrow{b} 0$.

Comment: In your link $\qquad\begin{align} 
  S &\to AB \mid BA \\
  A &\to a \mid aAa \mid aAb \mid bAa \mid bAb \\
  B &\to b \mid aBa \mid aBb \mid bBa \mid bBb 
\end{align}$ 


looks like the result can only have $2(2n+1)$ letters.

Comment: $S \to AB \to aAaB \to aaab$ and $|aaab| = 4$.

Comment: You got me there ... , A and B don't need to expand the same number of times.

Comment: everything is nice but i dont understand why L1 is regular. Can u write regular expression for this part? I would be grateful.

Comment: @Dago **that** part is really easy. Construct an automaton with states (0), (1), (2) starting with (0) and getting up when receiving a, and down when receiving b.

Comment: @Dago  Didn't look at the "regular expression" part. This might look messy in comparison. I trust the theorems that convert regular automatons to regular expressions.

Comment: i understand but this equality is in mod 3 . So how we can assure make for instance: aaa,bbbbbbbbb to match with ur automat?

Comment: I neglected to mention explicitly that (0)+>b->(2) and (2)+>a->(0). I hope you get me without formal definition of my ad hoc symbolization?

Comment: (0)@a ->(1), (0)@aaa=(3)==(0), (0)@b=(-1)==(2), (0)@bbb=(0)

Comment: hmm  i dont understand second post. Is there any way to easily send a picture of this automat? i  am really sory but i just dont see it ;/

Comment: Sorry, I don' know how to post pictures, but think of a as +1 and b as -1, draw a circle of states starting (0)->(1)->(2)->(0)==(3). Once you got the right 'click' in your brain it's relay easy.

Comment: ok so state 0 represent modulos? so 0 times of a,3 times of a or b, and so on? Plus what dou u mean b as - 1?

Comment: Yes, that' it. And if you are more happy with a formal definition, let the states be in $\mathbb Z /3\mathbb Z$ and $a=+1$ and $b=-1$. I'm far more worried about $L_0$, frankly, I don't understand the argument. Meanwhile, the automaton for $L_1$ is included in the answer.

Comment: i think i did. (0) ->a->(1)->-a>(2)->a->(0)-we go back(modulo) same for b's  but reverse order.